# Access Ruby on Rails 'public' directory without relative path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a flash object I wish to load and I believe the best place to store that asset is in the `public` directory. Suppose it's stored in `public/flash`, there must be a better way to path to the swf than what I've done below. Note the 'data' element, it has a relative path.

```
def create_vnc_object
  haml_tag :object, 
    :id => 'flash',
    :width => '100%', 
    :height => '100%',
    :type => 'application/x-shockwave-flash', 
    :data => '../../flash/flash.swf' do
      haml_tag :param, 
        :name => 'movie',
        :value => '../../flash/flash.swf'
  end
end
```

Is there some rails variable that points to `public`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't this work?

```
def create_vnc_object
  haml_tag :object, 
    :id => 'flash',
    :width => '100%', 
    :height => '100%',
    :type => 'application/x-shockwave-flash', 
    :data => '/flash/flash.swf' do
      haml_tag :param, 
        :name => 'movie',
        :value => '/flash/flash.swf'
  end
end
```

Alternatively you could use the `root_url` as the prefix:

```
def create_vnc_object
  haml_tag :object, 
    :id => 'flash',
    :width => '100%', 
    :height => '100%',
    :type => 'application/x-shockwave-flash', 
    :data => root_url + 'flash/flash.swf' do
      haml_tag :param, 
        :name => 'movie',
        :value => root_url + 'flash/flash.swf'
  end
end
```

The latter works only if you have the `root` route in your `routes.rb` file. It will point to the root of your site (e.g. `http://example.com/`) which is basically the `public` folder.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative method is to extend `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper`, which is most useful if you're using asset servers. This is the module that already implements `javascript_path` and `stylesheet_path`. You could do it like this:

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module AssetTagHelper
      def flash_movie_path(source)
        compute_public_path(source, 'flash', 'swf')
      end
      alias_method :path_to_flash_movie, :flash_movie_path
    end
  end
end
```

For reference, [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html) on `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper`.